# Selenium ( with Python ) doesn't start when I use a VPN

Tags: python, selenium, vpn

So I made a program that start a headless browser ( Chrome ) with Selenium in Python. 
I have a CyberGhost VPN.

When I try to start my script with the VPN active, Selenium open a chrome windows, with "data" in the url but doesn't proceed further. 
Otherwise, it works when I start the script with inactive VPN and turn the VPN on when selenium is running normally.

I don't understart what can be the problem ...

Thanks :)

Comment: Is the problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

VPN is handled at the OS level, before Selenium gets anywhere near. You can try to setup a config with `CyberGhostVPN` and run an exec command to start your connection. After that, then start Webdriver and it should be running over VPN. See here on [Calling an external command from Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

It may also be due to a firewall issue, so you can also try to deactivate the included firewall in `CyberGhostVPN`.